# Hide 'geometry' object on WFS GetFeature request for multiple TypeNames

Tags: geometry, wfs, features

I'm trying to fetch features for a WFS - but I'm not interested in the `Geometry` object. I would like to exclude it from the results...

Is there any way to do so?

I managed to define the `TYPENAME` parameter with the list of properties I needed for 1 specific Type. Following does not return the `Geometry` object. Perfect for this case...

```
SERVICE=WFS
&REQUEST=GetFeature
&VERSION=1.1.0
&MAXFEATURES=9999
&CRS=EPSG:31370
&BBOX=142562.4355,185629.719,142722.4355,185789.719
&OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json
&TYPENAME=Type1
&PROPERTYNAME=Property1,Property2
```

**Problem**

I want to call multiple types in a single `GetFeature` request.

I specify the list of `TYPENAME`...
I also define the list of `PROPERTYNAME`...

But the list of `PROPERTYNAME` contains values which don't occure in all `TYPENAME` items.

```
SERVICE=WFS
&REQUEST=GetFeature
&VERSION=1.1.0
&MAXFEATURES=9999
&CRS=EPSG:31370
&BBOX=142562.4355,185629.719,142722.4355,185789.719
&OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json
&TYPENAME=Type1,Type2,Type3,...
&PROPERTYNAME=Property1,Property2,Property3,...
```

Response as Exception:

```
Requested property:  Property3 is not available for Type1. The possible propertyName values are: ...
```

Following does not seem to change anything

```
&ows/wfs_geomtype=None
```

Is there any way to exclude the `GEOMTRY` object with above `WFS GetFeature` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bracket the propertyName lists -

```
typeName=topp:states,topp:tasmania_state_boundaries&propertyName=(STATE_ABBR,UNEMPLOY)(STATE,COUNTRY)
```

so something like this:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs\?service\=WFS\&request\=GetFeature\&version\=1.1.0\&typeName\=topp:states,topp:tasmania_state_boundaries\&propertyName\=\(STATE_ABBR,UNEMPLOY\)\(STATE,COUNTRY\)
```

Comment: THANKS!!!! Informational ... Let's say I have `&TYPENAME=Type1,Type2,Type3,...` then the `PROPERTYNAME` list has to be in the exact sequence like : `&PROPERTYNAME=Property1,Property2,Property3,...` or can it be defined as `&PROPERTYNAME=Property2,Property3,Property1,...`

Comment: I don't think the order matters, though the output will be in the schema order

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer from the WFS 1.1.0 standard http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=8339

**Example 10**

> Query some properties of a list of feature types. In this case, the
>   attributes wkbGeom and tileId are fetched for the InWaterA_1M feature
>   type and all the attributes of feature type BuiltUpA_1M are fetched.
>   http://www.someserver.com/wfs.cgi&

```
SERVICE=WFS&
VERSION=1.1.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
PROPERTY=(InWaterA_1M/wkbGeom,InWaterA_1M/tileId)(BuiltUpA_1M/*)&
TYPENAME=InWaterA_1M,BuiltUpA_1M
```

It is not necessary to use the typename/propertyname syntax but for sure it makes the query easier to read for humans.